# Docker image registry/repository on private cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, docker-registry

I installed Cloudfoundry (approximately version [v220](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/releases/tag/v220)) on OpenStack and I want to work with private Docker images on Cloudfoundry.

I would like to run docker registry/repository ([Doc](https://docs.docker.com/registry/)|[Github](https://github.com/docker/distribution)) server on Cloudfoundry.

1. I found tutorials on how to install it directly on a machine/VM ([1](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/deploying.md)|[2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)|[3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04)).

   - Is there something to be said against running it on Cloudfoundry?
   - How do I install it?
2. Is [Diego](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-release) or something like that already providing the registry/repository service?
3. I thought Diego was part of Cloudfoundry but reading the CF release notes it looks like I have to install Diego separately is that correct (see ["Recommended Diego Version"](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-release/releases/tag/v220))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run private Docker images on Cloudfoundry and there is a CF-specific registry you can use. In order to do that, there are a number of extra steps that you will need to undertake.

To answer your last question first, we must tease apart what exactly is meant by "Diego is a part of Cloud Foundry". Cloud Foundry is deployed using [BOSH](http://bosh.io/), which among other things has a concept of a `release`. A `release` is in essence a versioned collection of source code, configuration, dependencies, etc. that your system needs to run. I would recommend reading the BOSH docs to gain more of an understanding as to exactly what BOSH is.

Historically, Cloud Foundry has been made up of a single BOSH release, `cf-release`, but that is no longer the case. Diego itself is deployed as a separate release, `diego-release`, and that is what is being referred to in the `cf-release` release notes. To ensure compatibility, each release of `cf-release` publishes which release of `diego-release` is being run alongside.

Diego does support an internal docker registry that can run private docker images, but in order to do so, you must deploy another BOSH release and configure it correctly. That bosh release is the [diego-docker-cache-release](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-docker-cache-release), the README should hopefully help in getting you started. [This cf-dev post](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/list/cf-dev@lists.cloudfoundry.org/message/OPGSBCOIMWSCR76VQTU6VEDIPNEU4QGU/) by the current Diego PM might also be helpful in setting it up. If you run into any problems or issues, I would recommend posting to the [cf-dev mailing lists](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/) as the CF community and developers maintain a closer watch on that communication channel.